# System Event Handling using Java

Tags: java, events

I want to handle the system events through java program.

For example, if I want to insert a disc in dvd drive, I would click the eject option from a drop down box. I'll then handle that event and show the status as "Eject event generated".

How to do that one ? Which api is preferable ? Please help me.

I am using Ubuntu8 version os.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try writing appropriate *driver* in C/C++ and invoke it via JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Java is very much the wrong tool for this kind of thing. It doesn't *have* an API for general "system events" because those are very OS dependant and Java is designed to be OS-independant.